Value for in_feature not changing
I am making a deep learning model using resnet for multiclass classification and in it i am facing the problem of overfitting. To fix it i tried to reduce the layers of resnet and i am facing this error

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (65536x1 and 2048x1000)

my code is
class Flowers(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.classifier=nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),nn.Linear(in_features=1,out_features=102),
        )
def forward(self,x):
    x=self.classifier(x)
    return x
torch.manual_seed(42)
model = torch.hub.load("pytorch/vision", "resnet50", weights="IMAGENET1K_V2")
list(model.modules())
my_model = nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:12])
my_model.add_module('fc', Flowers())

it will be huge help if anyone can help me with the overfitting problem in general.

You cannot just convert an arbitrary model to a sequential one. Resnet is not sequential network.

what am i supposed to do to remove the last layer then @Ivan?

To remove the last layer without interfering with the model's inference, you can simply replace the fully connected layer with the identity function, nn.Identity:
model.fc = nn.Identity()

